# How to extract text using the coordinates from a .png with Tesseract/Python?

Tags: python, pdf, png, tesseract

I'm trying to give to my script "X" coordinates, in where is a text that i want to retrieve and later name the .png with that text. The thing is that the script reads the entire .png and give me all the text. I need to give to the script the coordinates (that i have) and then retrieve only the words that im looking for

```
import os
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
img = cv2.imread('example-1.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
resultado = print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))

#############################################
#### Detect characters ######
#############################################
hImg, wImg,_ = img.shape
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img)


for b in boxes.splitlines():
    # print(b)
    b = b.split(' ')
    # print(b)
    x, y, w, h = int(b[1]), int(b[2]), int(b[3]), int(b[4])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,hImg- y), (w,hImg- h), (50, 50, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(img,b[0],(x,hImg- y+25),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(50,50,255),2)
    print(b)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The coordinates of the words in the .png are these

```
['183', '2157', '203', '2197', '0']
['230', '2157', '250', '2199', '0']
['254', '2157', '274', '2187', '0']
['301', '2157', '319', '2197', '0']
['324', '2157', '345', '2187', '0']
['352', '2157', '362', '2199', '0']
['376', '2157', '386', '2197', '0']
['395', '2157', '415', '2187', '0']
```

Thanks! Greetings.

Comment: image_to_boxes gives coordinates for every character. You'll have to make extra code to figure out word coordinates. There might be an error in your x,y,w,h line. I think coordinates are the opposite corners of the bounding box and are x1,y1,x2,y2.

Comment: how would u do it?